# Открытие справки vscode клавиатурой

Tags: visual-studio-code

Когда я навожу мышкой на на функцию или переменную, то вскод показывает мне короткую справку(информацию). Я не люблю пользоваться мышкой, когда пишу код. Как я могу открыть эту справку хоткеем?